Difficult time in life
What if someone is going through a very difficult and uncertain period of life right now with serious concerns such as about money, not being married, profound anxiety about the future, etc. What can one do to have more emunah and bitachon to help get through this?

Find a competent rabbi, and consider a mental-health professional as well.

This is a question depending on the person but I'll give it a shot.
I feel like there is a misconception about what bitachon is (partly thanks to the story of R Yisrael Salanter and the gold watch).
My grandfather, Rav Eliezer Ben-David, would explain 2 puzzling verses in Ashrei (Tehillim 145:19-20).

רְצוֹן־יְרֵאָיו יַעֲשֶׂה וְאֶת־שַׁוְעָתָם יִשְׁמַע וְיוֹשִׁיעֵם׃ שׁוֹמֵר יְהֹוָה אֶת־כׇּל־אֹהֲבָיו

Love of Hashem is greater than fear of Hashem (Sotah 31a). Yet the verse only says Hashem does the desires of those who fear him, those who love his get protection but not their desires. Hashem gives those who fear him what they want so they continue fearing him, this is sometimes to their detriment (such as saving a city because of Lot's prayer but Lot ending up in a cave with his daughters B'reshit 19:18-38). The one who loves Hashem will not question Hashem when he doesn't get his desired response, so Hashem may not listen to him in the first place for his own benefit.
The source of Emunah is being happy with what one has (see Avot 4:1). The opening line of Mesillat Yesharim is

יִּתְבָּרֵר וְיִתְאַמֵּת אֵצֶל הָאָדָם מָה חוֹבָתוֹ בְּעוֹלָמוֹ
a man has to clarify and come to realize as truth what is his obligation in his world

His world is his own world, what he has, not what he wants to have. Some people unfortunately don't get the best portion in this world (like the ibn Ezra). One should focus on all the good that Hashem does give him that

Even if our mouths were filled with song like the sea, and our tongues with exultation like the roaring of its waves, and our lips with praise like the breadth of the firmament, and our eyes were radiant like the sun and the moon, and our hands outspread like [the] eagles of the sky, and our feet light as the deer— we would never sufficiently thank You Hashem (Nishmat Kol Hai).

